# How to put result from database interrogation into a List<String[]> - java

Tags: java, database

I want to use a method that extracts a list of id's from my database. I managed to do so with List String  but it won't work with List String[], which i really need to obtain.This is my try statement:

```
try {
        connection = getJNDIConnection(connectionName);
        pstmt = connection.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);
         // set the input parameters
        pstmt.setLong(1, groupId);
        resultSet = pstmt.executeQuery();
        if (resultSet.next()) {
            result = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            do {
                Array resultStr = resultSet.getArray(1);
                result.addAll(resultStr);//here is the problem
                if (Constants.DEBUG_MODE.equals("true")) {
                    logger.debug("[{}] Get the customers list id from database GROUPS_CUSTOMERS table={}", methodName, result);
                }
            } while(resultSet.next());
        }
    }
```

Eclipse is giving me back this message : "The method addAll(Collection) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Array) ".
Can i try something else? 
Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks, will you please try to help, though?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because `Array` is not an implementation of `Collection` interface. You can try the following:

```
String[] arr = (String[]) resultSet.getArray(1).getArray();
result.add(arr);
```

Hope the cast in the first line works. If not, you'll have to find the actual type you need to cast to by using a debugger.